# Microsoft MFCreateFMPEG4MediaSink to Create DASH compliant mp4 files

Tags: fragment, mp4, ms-media-foundation, mpeg-dash

Is it possible to create DASH compliant Mp4 files with MFCreateFMPEG4MediaSink.

The API says MFCreateFMPEG4MediaSink supports fragmented mp4. Is this the default behavior or do we need to set some flags.

When I try to play files generated by MFCreateFMPEG4MediaSink in MediaSource in javascript, it does not play. 
I inspect the generated file with MP4Box.js and it says it is not fragmented.

Thanks
UPDATE:

```
  IMFMediaBuffer * pBuffer;
    // Create a new memory buffer.
    HRESULT hr = MFCreateMemoryBuffer(data_length, &pBuffer);

    BYTE *pData = NULL;
    // Lock the buffer and copy the video frame to the buffer.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        DWORD buffLen = data_length;
        hr = pBuffer->Lock(&pData,NULL, NULL);
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        memcpy(pData, data, data_length);
    }

    if (pBuffer)
    {
        pBuffer->Unlock();
    }

    // Set the data length of the buffer.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pBuffer->SetCurrentLength(data_length);
    }

    // Create a media sample and add the buffer to the sample.
    IMFSample * pSample;
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = MFCreateSample(&pSample);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pSample->AddBuffer(pBuffer);
    }

    // Set the time stamp and the duration.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pSample->SetSampleTime(rtStart);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pSample->SetSampleDuration(video_frame_duration);
    }
    rtStart += video_frame_duration;
    /*if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pSample->SetUINT32(MFSampleExtension_CleanPoint, isIDR);
    }*/
    //pSample->
    // Send the sample to the Sink Writer.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pSinkWriter->WriteSample(0, pSample);
    }

    SafeRelease(&pSample);
    SafeRelease(&pBuffer);
    return 1;
```

THIS IS WHERE I CREATE THE SINKER

```
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = MFCreateMediaType(&pMediaType);
    }
    //unsigned char * pSeqHdr = reinterpret_cast<UINT8 *>(mSamplesQueue.SequenceHeader());
    /*
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pMediaType->SetBlob(MF_MT_MPEG_SEQUENCE_HEADER, blob, 25);
    }
    UINT32 pcbBlobSize = { 0 };
    hr = pMediaType->GetBlobSize(MF_MT_MPEG_SEQUENCE_HEADER, &pcbBlobSize);
    */


    /*if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = pMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MPEG4SINK_MOOV_BEFORE_MDAT, 1);
    }*/
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_H264);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaType, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, frame_rate, 1);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE, bit_rate);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, MFVideoInterlace_Progressive);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = MFSetAttributeSize(pMediaType, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, width, height);
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Pixel aspect ratio
        hr = MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaType, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1);
    }


if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = MFCreateFile(
            MF_ACCESSMODE_READWRITE,
            MF_OPENMODE_DELETE_IF_EXIST,
            MF_FILEFLAGS_NONE,
            L"output2temp.mp4",
            &pByteStream);
    }

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = MFCreateMPEG4MediaSink(
            pByteStream,
            pMediaType,
            NULL,
            &pMediaSink);
    }
```

Comment: `MFCreateFMPEG4MediaSink` always creates [fragmented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35180327/868014) MP4 file (with `moof` atoms).

Comment: I just rechecked and I do not have any moof atoms. How do I force it to appear.

Comment: The code snippet you added as an update looks irrelevant, it does not even have `MFCreateFMPEG4MediaSink ` call

Comment: Yeah I Thought maybe it has something got to do with appending the samples.

Comment: Added the part where I create the mp4

Comment: Your code snippet does `MFCreateMPEG4MediaSink` (without F) and you claim that `MFCreateFMPEG4MediaSink` does not work as expected.

Comment: OMG THANKS. I almost started implementing my muxer with all that moof moov ftyp box.Thanks Roman Life saver.  I did not see that "F".

Comment: For everyone looking at this, I found
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49429954/mfcreatefmpeg4mediasink-does-not-generate-mse-compatible-mp4